# Data Frame Initialization - Character Initialization read as Factors?

Tags: r

I am trying to initialize a data frame like this as I would like to have an empty data frame with two character vectors as columns

```
out_frame<-data.frame(Hospital = character(), State = character()
```

However, when I look at class of each column for this data frame, it shows a factor? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please read the help file for `data.frame`

Comment: `?data.frame`: "*Character variables passed to ‘data.frame’ are converted
     to factor columns unless protected by ‘I’ or argument
     ‘stringsAsFactors’ is false*"

Answer (score 1):

The data.frame function takes the following argument "stringsAsFactors".
By default it is set to TRUE. Set it to FALSE to keep character from being cast to factors.

```
out_frame <- data.frame(Hospital = character(), State = character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(out_frame)
```